# How to have polymorph property in EF 6 CF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.6

I need to have some complex properties in EF, one of them is polymoph. I have followed this article to serialize my complex types to and from JSON: http://www.reddnet.net/entity-framework-json-column/.

I have tried to add the polymorph property using the interface I declared as data type for that property. As the interface prescribes the same *Serialized* property for all implementations, mapping looks straightforward... well, it is not, as the DBContext won't instantiate, saying that my interface type is not mapped (althrough I tried to set up with ComplexTypeConfiguration too).

Than I found this article: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449331825/ch08s04.html, saying that Interfaces are just not supported, and there is no real workaround.

I am posting this question hoping that somebody still knows one.

Thank you.

Comment: I might have found a workaround. Not absolutelly transparent, but working correctly. I will probably make a post of it.

Comment: Well, I havent :(. What I achived is some kind of write-once property, which is not usable...